# is there a way to detect chinese characters in c++ ? (using boost)

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-locale

In a data processing project, i need to detect split words in chinese ( words in chinese dont contain spaces).
Is there a way to detect chinese characters using a native c++ feature or boost.locale library ?

Comment: How is the input encoded? UTF-8? There are a few libraries available that can handle UTF-8 encoded input and convert to some other encoding (e.g. UTF-32). A UTF-32 encoded character is easy to check if it falls into a certain range, like the one for some specific Chinese character set.

Comment: Please provide what kind of data you have. Is this a wide character or regular character string? Also what kind of encoding is used?

Comment: Its UTF-8 encoded data, i am working with chars or boost segments to get unicode code points @some

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my attempt using only boost and standard library:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex/pending/unicode_iterator.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

using Iter = boost::u8_to_u32_iterator<std::string::const_iterator>;

template <::boost::uint32_t a, ::boost::uint32_t b>
class UnicodeRange
{
    static_assert(a <= b, "Proper range");
public:
    constexpr bool operator()(::boost::uint32_t x) const noexcept
    {
        return x >= a && x <= b;
    }
};

using UnifiedIdeographs = UnicodeRange<0x4E00, 0x9FFF>;
using UnifiedIdeographsA = UnicodeRange<0x3400, 0x4DBF>;
using UnifiedIdeographsB = UnicodeRange<0x20000, 0x2A6DF>;
using UnifiedIdeographsC = UnicodeRange<0x2A700, 0x2B73F>;
using UnifiedIdeographsD = UnicodeRange<0x2B740, 0x2B81F>;
using UnifiedIdeographsE = UnicodeRange<0x2B820, 0x2CEAF>;
using CompatibilityIdeographs = UnicodeRange<0xF900, 0xFAFF>;
using CompatibilityIdeographsSupplement = UnicodeRange<0x2F800, 0x2FA1F>;

constexpr bool isChineese(::boost::uint32_t x) noexcept
{
    return UnifiedIdeographs{}(x) 
    || UnifiedIdeographsA{}(x) || UnifiedIdeographsB{}(x) || UnifiedIdeographsC{}(x) 
    || UnifiedIdeographsD{}(x) || UnifiedIdeographsE{}(x)
    || CompatibilityIdeographs{}(x) || CompatibilityIdeographsSupplement{}(x);
}

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, s))
    {
        auto start = std::find_if(Iter{s.cbegin()}, Iter{s.cend()}, isChineese);
        auto stop = std::find_if_not(start, Iter{s.cend()}, isChineese);
        std::cout << std::string{start.base(), stop.base()} << '\n';
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/FtxKa8D2LtR3ko9t

Probably you should be able to polish that approach to something fully functional.
I do not know how to properly cover this by tests and not sure which characters should be included in this check.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, if you want full Unicode support in C++, there is little to no way around [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/). Boost provides some access to its features (through Boost.Locale and Boost.Regex), but it requires Boost to be compiled with ICU support for this. So instead of making sure the Boost of the target platform is compiled thusly you are probably better off using the ICU API directly.

If you are looking for word boundaries, [icu::BreakIterator](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/classicu_1_1BreakIterator.html) (more specifically, [icu::BreakIterator::createWordInstance](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/classicu_1_1BreakIterator.html#a1266dc4f44f0d8614b3060ece504f786)) is the starting point. You then pass the text to be iterated over via [setText](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/classicu_1_1BreakIterator.html#a8b894129fb567fded3ed85a7e8ead942) and move the iterator via [next](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/classicu_1_1BreakIterator.html#a13468dd341e9f0eb92c61f25e88a5154) et al. (yes, ICU is a bit non-idiomatic this way, as it originated in Java land).

Alternatively, if you don't want to go for the full C++ API, there's [ublock_getCode](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/uchar_8h.html#a4e77b605d178b6b79638e5bea57927df) which will tell you the [UBlockCode](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/uchar_8h.html#a19f1662c9c33c31593612d05777ea901) of the code point in question.

Comment: Yeah, that's the reason i avoid ICU in the first place, it's not STL friendly, been working with boost.locale so get segments and iterate over them

Comment: @AdnaneHmunna: I understand that, but I've also been in that place to ship a Unicode-aware application for Windows targets... since there are no official pre-compiled Boost binaries for Windows, let alone with ICU-support compiled in... there just is no alternative, really, and I personally **need** that Unicode support. So I decided that a not-so-idiomatic API is better than a broken or unreliable one... I can't really make any better suggestion. If you have Boost.Locale and Boost.Regex with ICU compiled in, feel free to use that. I just can't recommend it for the maintenance headache.

Comment: @AdnaneHmunna: Added a reference to the C API function identifying a code point's block. Perhaps that's more palatable for your purposes. Wrapping custom-picked parts of the ICU API (either C or C++) into something more idiomatic is also an option.

Comment: Aren't the MSVC binaries linked [here](https://www.boost.org/users/download/) (under "Other Downloads") "official"?

Comment: @Quentin: Gee, those weren't even there when I last looked. But 1) they are provided "by members of the community", which is why they are listed under "Other Downloads" (which wouldn't really matter much to most people, admittedly), and 2) come without ICU support. ;-)